# Default gateway metric in systemd-networkd

Tags: systemd-networkd

Why is systemd-network giving a statically configured network the metric 0?

If I configure an interface with DHCP I get the metric 1024:

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
```

The output of `ip route`:

```
default via 10.245.111.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 10.245.111.96 metric 1024
```

However If I configure the network with a static gateway the metric is 0:

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
Address=10.245.111.96/24
Gateway=10.245.111.1
DNS=10.245.111.1
```

The output of `ip route` (no metric meaning 0):

```
default via 10.245.111.1 dev eth0 proto static
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can delete the `Gateway=` directive from the `[Network]` section, and specify it in a separate `[Route]` section, then you can bundle it with a `Metric=` directive.

From the official documentation: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html#Gateway=

> This is a short-hand for a `[Route]` section only containing a `Gateway` key.

A working example for your configuration:

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
Address=10.245.111.96/24
DNS=10.245.111.1

[Route]
Gateway=10.245.111.1
Metric=1024
```